# UIButton addTarget:action:ForControlEvents not working

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, action, selector

i am getting a view out of a nib like so:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostitView" owner:self options:nil];
viewPostit = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

then I add the following to it:

```
[viewPostit.btnAction addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSavePostitClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The view and all the other controls I add custom properties to works perfectly. But when I click that button, no event gets triggered and I dont know why.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

```
-(void) btnSavePostitClicked:(id)sender
{}
```

Thank you

Tom

Comment: what class is `viewPostit`? how is `btnAction` defined and set? are you sure `btnAction` isn't nil at this time?

Comment: viewPostit is just a custom view. Apparently it wasnt one of my best days yesterday. As I found out this morning, the parent view is stealing all the touches, which is somehow weird, because that viewPostit is on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked btnAction in IB ?

Comment: No, bec the idea is to link the btnAction dynamic to the viewcontrollers which uses it. linking the btnAction to a method inside the view itself doesnt seem correct to me.

Comment: Not linked to an IBAction, but with an IBOutlet

Comment: Yes, i did. I solved the issue already, please see above. Thanks for your time mate!